# Autorelease objects in ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, automatic-ref-counting, autorelease

Suppose in my Database Manager which is singleton.

```
+ (SWDatabaseManager *)retrieveManager
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
       if (!sharedSingleton)
       {
           sharedSingleton = [[SWDatabaseManager alloc] init];
       }
       return sharedSingleton;
    }
}

- (NSArray *)getProductDetails:(NSString *)someString 
{
    NSArray *temp = [self getRowsForQuery:someString];
    return temp;
}

- (NSArray *)getRowsForQuery:(NSString *)sql
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement=nil;
    NSMutableArray *arrayResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:1];
    //
    //Fetching data from database and adds them in to arrayResults
    //
    return arrayResults;
}
```

Now from some view controller i am calling function of Database manager like this....

```
[self getProductServiceDidGetDetail:[[SWDatabaseManager retrieveManager] getProductDetail: @"SomeQuery"]

- (void)getProductServiceDidGetDetail:(NSArray *)detailArray 
{
    [self setDataSource:[NSArray arrayWithArray:detailArray]];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Questions are ... 
When arrayResult of getRowsForQuery will release?

Do i need to assign nil to detailArray of getProductServiceDidGetDetail?

Is there any memory leaks?

Suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't prefix methods with `get`;  that is reserved for a very particular use case of which this is not one.

Comment: Check for memory leaks using [Instruments](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/instruments-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-debug-memory-leaks). You can also see where, when and how much memory gets allocated when using your app.

Comment: If I answered your question properly, please accept it. please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARC does automatic memory management. So it releases everything (your array), when you are done using it.

> ARC works by adding code at compile time to ensure that objects live
>   as long as necessary, but no longer. Conceptually, it follows the same
>   memory management conventions as manual reference counting (described
>   in Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide) by adding the
>   appropriate memory management calls for you.

To help you understand better you might want to read apples docs on [ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html).

You will not need to assign nil to the array, nor do you have to worry about memory leaks.

> You do not have to (indeed cannot) release instance variables, but you
>   may need to invoke [self setDelegate:nil] on system classes and other
>   code that isn’t compiled using ARC.